# Read CSS file in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can anyone tell me how can i read a css file from my UI project directory in angularjs. I am doing a get call but not able to get the CSS but getting index.html  file in output.

Can anyone tell me what will be the possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hi,
We're in lack of context, can you please provide the aimed piece of code?
By the way, if you call for a css file and get html, it's certainly the html of a 404 page, check the url path.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a minimalist CSS parsing object a long time ago. It doesn't use Angular, but might give you the needed hint for reading CSS files via JS. The object declaration can be seen at:

https://pastebin.com/k2smWS0M

```
this.getSheetByHref = function(href) {}
```

is the bit you'd likely need.